# Poppler pdftohtml.exe fails to load through IIS7

Tags: python-3.x, flask, iis-7, windows-server-2012-r2, poppler

We are using poppler's pdftohtml exe to convert pdf to html. When we running it through flask then it working properly. But once we deploy on IIS then it is throwing below error at the time of using subprocess for pdftohtml.exe in event viewer.

**Faulting application name: pdftohtml.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5e08ef38 Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19678, time stamp: 0x5e82c88a Exception code: 0xc000007b Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecf40 Faulting process id: 0x2b08 Faulting application start time: 0x01d686ac57ca0b65 Faulting application path: C:\HOLDSPROD\poppler-0.84.0-h1affe6b_0\Library\bin\pdftohtml.exe Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id: 961fde3c-f29f-11ea-80f0-000d3aa29228 Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID:**

From python we are using subprocess to open the cmd.exe and passing the parameters to poppler's exe.
Same issue for pdftoppm.exe(to convert from pdf to image).

Note: This application is wrapped with .net and we have deployed the application on IIS 7.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to my search for the component and error, and the description in the document. The error represented by the exception code is invalid name. Maybe some problems happened about your filename, directory name or volume label syntax. So I suggest you check these.Confirm the path of exe file is right. If possible, you'd better put it under project floder, assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission the site folder.

Comment: As I said it is working when we deploy it through flask. It is creating an issue once we deploy on IIS.

Comment: We have also tried giving complete permission for iis_usrs and iusr but no impact.

Comment: You can check the permissions of the application pool. Insufficient permissions will also make it impossible to call this file. The application pool can be set to localsystem, which has the highest authority.